# How to find $\frac{\tan(x+y)}{\tan(x)}$ if $5\sin(2x+y)=7\sin(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I saw this problem Find  $\frac{\tan(x+y)}{\tan(x)}$ if $5\sin(2x+y)=7\sin(y)$

I tried to use $$\sin(x+y)\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)\sin(x)= \frac{7}{5}\sin(y)$$
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\frac{7}{5}\frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(x+y)}- \sin(x) }{\cos(x)}$$

$$\frac{\tan(x+y)}{\tan(x)}={\frac{7}{5}\frac{\sin(y)}{\sin(x)\cos(x+y)}- 1 }$$

Which lead to nothing.

I also tried to use $\tan(a+b)$ formula but it also didn't lead to anything useful.

Comment: $x=y=0$ satisifies the hypothesis but $\tan w/\tan x$ is not defined in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $w = x + y$ , then the given equation becomes:

$5 \sin( x + w ) = 7 \sin(w - x) $

and we want $\tan(w)/\tan x$.  Expanding:

$5 ( \sin x \cos w + \cos x \sin w ) = 7 (\sin w \cos x - \cos w \sin x )$

So,

$12 \sin x \cos w = 2 \sin w \cos x$

which gives:

$12 \tan x = 2 \tan w $

Therefore,

$\dfrac{\tan w}{\tan x} = 6$

Comment: A small point to note: $\tan w/\tan x$ need not be defined. For example, $x=y=0$ satisifies the hypothesis but $\tan w/\tan x$ is not defined in this case.

Comment: Such kinds of questions are usually not about existence or domain, rather value in the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Observe that $\dfrac{2x+y+\ \ y}2=?,\dfrac{2x+y-\ \ y}2=?$

$$\dfrac{\sin(2x+y)}{\sin y}=\dfrac75$$

Apply [Componendo & Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/)

$$\dfrac{7+5}{7-5}=\dfrac{\sin(2x+y)+\sin y}{\sin(2x+y)-\sin y}$$

Apply [Prosthaphaeresis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula for $tan(x+y)$ and expanding gives
$$\frac{\tan x +\tan y}{\tan x(1-\tan x \tan y)}$$
Converting everything to sin and cos gives

$$\frac{\sin{x}\cos{x}\cos{y} + \sin{y}\cos^2{x}}{\sin{x}\cos{x}\cos{y} - \sin{y}\sin^2{x}}$$
Using the formula for $sin(2x)$ and the identities $\cos^2{x} = (1+\cos2x)/2$, $\sin^2{x} = (1-\cos2x)/2$ we get

$$\frac{\sin(2x+y)/2+\sin(y)/2}{\sin(2x+y)/2-\sin(y)/2}$$

I think you can finish after this.